# Project rider - see msbuild output when building

Tags: msbuild, rider

I want to see the msbuild log when I try to build the solution.

It was originally a Visual studio 2015 solution.

The output build window of Rider (View --> Tool Windows --> Build) is showing:

> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1 Copyright (C)
>   Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 
>   Build started 10/2/2016
>   10:28:29 AM. Build succeeded

And the VS2015 Build windows shows:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: P1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ 
>   2>------ Build started: Project: P2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ 
>   3>------ Build started: Project: P3, Configuration: Debug
>   Any CPU ------
>  
>   . 
>   . 
>   . 
>   1>  P1 -> D:\dev\TQS\src\P1\bin\P1.dll 
>   2>  P2 -> D:\dev\TQS\src\P2\bin\Debug\P2.dll 
>   3>  P3 -> D:\dev\TQS\src\P3\bin\Debug\P3.dll
>   ========== Build: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 3 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Does anyone know why the differences?

Comment: Have you tried to check what is inside Build output? - it's available in: View->Tool Windows->Build

Comment: Thanks @PiKos - Please see my Edit

Comment: One difference, that could be worked-around by the rider guys, but still, is that [VS doesn't use MSBuild to build the solution as a whole](https://twitter.com/davkean/status/1000365579016986624), but calls it for every project individually. The `---- Build started:...` and `=== Build : 3 succeeded...` lines come from VS not MSBuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very likely that you need to wait till a newer EAP. The current build of Rider does not give you options to change MSBuild/xbuild verbosity. Also its Build window output style differs. You can also raise a bug report to JetBrains if you do want it to follow VS style.

Answer (score 1):

Feature "ReSharper Build"([blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/10/15/introducing-resharper-build/)
, [docs](http://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Building_Solution.html)) is enabled by default in Rider and disabled in ReSharper.
In settings ("ReSharper->Options->Tools->ReSharper Build" for ReSharper and "Build, Execution, Deployment->Toolset and Build" for Rider) your can configure it

Answer (score 1):

Rider just introduced the option to log build output and set up the log verbosity. You can check out here:
[How to diagnose build problems](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000083659-How-to-diagnose-build-problems)

Open settings, enable 'Write log to file' option, and set verbosity to 'Diagnostic'

[image]

'Rebuild Solution with Diagnostic', the log file will open automatically

[image]