# Logs are not displayed while running the ASP.NET Core 2.1 application with Rider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, jetbrains-ide, rider, jetbrains-rider

Using Rider to run the ASP.NET Core application, the logs are not displayed while running the application. I have below `launch.setting` file:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:22742/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "xxxxx.xxxx.app": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:22742/"
    }
  }
}
```

On the console, I can see only below code:

[image]

How can I see all the logs, what is happening behind the scene?

Comment: What are you using for logging? How logging section of application settings does look like?

Comment: There are quite a few settings controlling ASP.NET Core log entries, so without post those this question is impossible to be answered, https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Dec/31/Dont-let-ASPNET-Core-Default-Console-Logging-Slow-your-App-down

Comment: @GuruStron I am looking for the build process logs

Comment: @LexLi I am not looking for the application logs, I am more concern about build process logs during running the application at the begining

Comment: I answered that kind of questions a while ago, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39227152/project-rider-see-msbuild-output-when-building and Rider now has similar settings, https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000083659-How-to-diagnose-build-problems

Comment: Whether you are using [Asp.net core Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to add the log or using a third party package to add log? Try to use Visual Studio 2019, Visual Studio code or dotnet CLI to run the application and check whether the log is there? If the log still disappears, please check your code, whether you have enabled logging or not, and the log level. If you can see the log, the issue relates the Rider setting, you could contact with the Rider team.